# React lifecycle events cancel GSAP animation

Tags: reactjs, animation, gsap

I'm trying to use GSAP with React and I'm running into this situation where my animation gets cancelled.

My component is a Sidebar that appears only if the 'show' property in the state is true. Inside the component, my main functions are:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) { 
  return nextState.show !== this.state.show; 
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextState == true) {
    // animate the sidebar in
  } else {
    // animate the sidebar out
  }
}

toggleSidebar() { 
  const newState = !this.state.show;
  this.setState({ show: newState })
}
```

For some reason, when I click my button to trigger the toggleSidebar function, the sidebar begins to animate in and then immediately animates out.

I have a feeling its because the componentWillUpdate returns too soon but I'm not sure.

At this point, I'm thinking of just using TransitionGroup and including the GSAP animation code in the componentWillEnter / componentWillLeave lifecycle hooks so that they can function properly but I'm curious if there's any way to solve this issue.

Comment: Always use *Did* if possible, *Will* could have some nasty side effects.

Answer (score 0):

One common reason is that `toggleSidebar` gets called twice. This happens sometimes with the Safari Browser, but I also saw some cases in the Chrome Browser. You could either try to use `e.preventDefault` on the receiving event from your Button click or use the old fashion boolean flag e.g.

```
toggleSidebar() {
    if (isAnimating) {
        isAnimating = !isAnimating;
        return;
    }
    isAnimating = true;
    const newState = !this.state.show;
    this.setState({
        show: newState
    })
}
```

Comment: Hm I tried both methods and console logged from toggleMenu and it seems like it's only being called once.